# unique_ptr and polymorphism

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have some code that currently uses raw pointers, and I want to change to smart pointers. This helps cleanup the code in various ways. Anyway, I have factory methods that return objects and its the caller's responsibility to manager them. Ownership isn't shared and so I figure `unique_ptr` would be suitable. The objects I return generally all derive from a single base class, `Object`.

For example,

```
class Object { ... };
class Number : public Object { ... };
class String : public Object { ... };

std::unique_ptr<Number> State::NewNumber(double value)
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<Number>(new Number(this, value));
    }

std::unique_ptr<String> State::NewString(const char* value)
    {
        return std::unique_ptr<String>(new String(this, value));
    }
```

The objects returned quite often need to be passed to another function, which operates on objects of type `Object` (the base class). Without any smart pointers the code is like this.

```
void Push(const Object* object) { ... } // push simply pushes the value contained by object onto a stack, which makes a copy of the value
Number* number = NewNumber(5);
Push(number);
```

When converting this code to use `unique_ptrs` I've run into issues with polymorphism. Initially I decided to simply change the definition of `Push` to use `unique_ptrs` too, but this generates compile errors when trying to use derived types. I could allocate objects as the base type, like

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> number = NewNumber(5);
```

and pass those to `Push` - which of course works. However I often need to call methods on the derived type. In the end I decided to make `Push` operate on a pointer to the object stored by the `unique_ptr`.

```
void Push(const Object* object) { ... }
std::unique_ptr<Object> number = NewNumber(5);
Push(number.get());
```

Now, to the reason for posting. I'm wanting to know if this is the normal way to solve the problem I had? Is it better to have `Push` operate on the `unique_ptr` vs the object itself?  If so how does one solve the polymorphism issues? I would assume that simply casting the ptrs wouldn't work. Is it common to need to get the underlying pointer from a smart pointer?

Thanks, sorry if the question isn't clear (just let me know).

edit: I think my Push function was a bit ambiguous. It makes a copy of the underlying value and doesn't actually modify, nor store, the input object.

Comment: "However I often need to call methods on the derived type..." So this is a design issue. You are trying to use polymorphism with objects that aren't polymorphic.

Comment: By that I mean in the code that's calling the Push function. So the owner of the created object first does things on the created object, and what it does differs based on what type it is. The issue arises when I want to call Push on that object.

Comment: well new edit does help the cause. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Initially I decided to simply change the definition of Push to use
>   unique_ptrs too, but this generates compile errors when trying to use
>   derived types.

You likely did not correctly deal with uniqueness.

```
void push(std::unique_ptr<int>);
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> i;
    push(i); // Illegal: tries to copy i.
}
```

If this compiled, it would trivially break the invariant of `unique_ptr`, that only one `unique_ptr` owns an object, because both `i` and the local argument in `push` would own that `int`, so it is illegal. `unique_ptr` is *move only*, it's not copyable. It has nothing to do with derived to base conversion, which `unique_ptr` handles completely correctly.

If `push` owns the object, then use `std::move` to move it there. If it doesn't, then use a raw pointer or reference, because that's what you use for a non-owning alias.

Comment: When I tried using the `unique_ptr` I tried passing by reference, like `void push(const std::unique_ptr<Object>& object)` but regardless, your answer clarifies things. For some reason I thought that getting the underlying pointer from a smart one was a dirty thing to do and should be avoided. But this is not the case?

Comment: @user1520427: Reference to pointer is the thing that will prevent polymorphism, because the uniqe_ptr specializations are unrelated types. You have to use reference to the object itself.

Comment: @user1520427: No, it's fine to do that. But your solution would require copying the `unique_ptr<Number>` to a `unique_ptr<Object>` and then referring to that- which involves copying it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if your functions operate on the (pointed to) object itself and don't need its address, neither take any ownership, and, as I guess, always need a valid object (fail when passed a `nullptr`), why do they take pointers at all?

Do it properly and make them take references:

```
void Push(const Object& object) { ... }
```

Then the calling code looks exactly the same for raw and smart pointers:

```
auto number = NewNumber(5);
Push(*number);
```

**EDIT:** But of course no matter if using references or pointers, don't make `Push` take a `std::unique_ptr` if it doesn't take ownership of the passed object (which would make it steal the ownership from the passed pointer). Or in general don't use owning pointers when the pointed to object is not to be owned, `std::shared_ptr` isn't anything different in this regard and is as worse a choice as a `std::unique_ptr` for `Push`'s parameter if there is no ownership to be taken by `Push`.

Answer (score 3):

If `Push` does not take owenrship, it should probably take reference instead of pointer. And most probably a `const` one. So you'll have

```
Push(*number);
```

Now that's obviously only valid if Push isn't going to keep the pointer anywhere past it's return. If it does I suspect you should try to rethink the ownership first.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a polymorphism example using unique pointer:

```
vector<unique_ptr<ICreature>> creatures;

creatures.emplace_back(new Human);
creatures.emplace_back(new Fish);

unique_ptr<vector<string>> pLog(new vector<string>());

for each (auto& creature in creatures)
{
    auto state = creature->Move(*pLog);
}
```