# C++ container full of abstract objects

Tags: c++, stl

My background is primarily C and Java (with a smattering of other things), and have started working on a project in C++.  My exact task is generating a set of objects from a configuration file (that is, read the file, determine what sort of object to create, add it to a list, repeat).  The problematic part is equivalent to the following:

(I'm using C `char*` syntax because I can easily write it for the example here -- presume I don't actually know how many I need as well, which is why I would like to use `vector`)

```
class General {
    public:
        virtual int f()=0;
};
class SpecificA : public General {
    public:
        virtual int f();
};
class SpecificB : public General {
    public:
        virtual int f();
};
std::vector<General> build(char** things, int number) {
    std::vector<General> result;
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++) {
        if(strcmp(things[i],"A")) {
            result.push_back(SpecificA());
        } else if(strcmp(things[i],"B")) {
            result.push_back(SpecificB());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This won't work, because I can't have a `vector` of `General`, because you can never actually have an instance of `General`.  From various places I have read,

- I should use pointers so that the polymorphism works correctly
- C++ pointers should almost never actually be needed because they're not necessary, automatic pointers are almost always better when you do need them, and usually you can use references instead
- Large `struct`s (such as classes) should be passed by reference rather than copied around and returned from functions
- It's totally fine to return full objects in C++

It's beginning to feel a little like C++ wants me to use the memory practices of Java using the tools of C, and it's really not working.  At this point I'm getting quite tempted to throw any kind of best practices involving automatic memory allocation out the window and litter my code with `*`'s, but I'd like to hear if there's a "right" way of doing this first.

Comment: You need a `General*` or a [smart pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer).  [isocpp.org](https://isocpp.org/) has a great [FAQ on this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/virtual-functions)

Comment: Automatic pointers are (indeed) pretty close to Java's references and are (except for automatic memory management) almost exactly the same as plain naked pointers in C. At least for your purposes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13288394/unique-ptr-and-polymorphism

Comment: Use vector of `unique_ptr` if you want the objects to be destroyed when they are removed from the vector, and use `shared_ptr` if you want them to work like Java references.

Comment: You do not seem to understand best practices you are referring to. First, you should use pointers *or references* for polymorphism to work. Second, there is nothing wrong in plain pointer as long as it is not managed. For instance, const char* is a wonderful thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use unique_ptr in a following way:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<General>> build(char** things, int number) {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<General>> result;
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++) {
        if(strcmp(things[i],"A")) {
            result.push_back(std::unique_ptr<General>(new SpecificA()));
        } else if(strcmp(things[i],"B")) {
            result.push_back(std::unique_ptr<General>(new SpecificB()));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if people would compile your code before posting it here... Your code won't even compile. I wonder who upvoted it.

Comment: I did. It's got the correct idea and the error about the non-implicit conversion isn't a big problem.

Comment: @Puppy, are you the same person as Ilya? ;)

Comment: Nope, he's simply the first to get the correct answer in this case.

Comment: @Puppy, Ok, I misread your comment. When you said 'I did' I somehow read it (I did compile my code). The rest of confusion came from this. On the substance, I am pretty sure, OP would have no idea how to fix the compilation error.

Comment: That's true, which is why I fixed it, as could pretty much anybody.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in your code is that you're trying to work with polymorphic objects directly, rather than by pointers or references. And C++ doesn't work this way.

Objects in C++ have (among other things) a size. This size is fixed and doesn't change. All C++ machinery is built around this idea. An object of class `A` it occupies `sifeof(A)` bytes. An array of n objects of class `A` occupies `n * sizeof(A)` bytes since it contains n continuously allocated objects of type `A`. Having this fixed size makes pointer arithmetics and constant-time member access operator possible.

Now, objects of different classes within a hierarchy can have different sizes. Here's an example:

```
struct Base {
   virtual void f() { std::cout << "Base\n"; }
};

struct Derived: Base {
    void f() override { std::cout << "Derived\n"; }
    int m_value = 0;
};
```

It's pretty obvious that `sizeof(Base) != sizeof(Derived)` since the latter has the `m_value` member. So in order to store any object of this hierarchy (that is either `Base` or `Derived`) you now need at least `sizeof(Derived)` bytes. This is:

1. Wasteful
2. Not easily achievable since your class hierarchy can be scattered across different translation units (you can have another class that derives from `Base` and has additional class members)

Both of this problems can be solved with indirection. Instead of storing the objects themselves you can store something that is fixed in size, but can point to objects of different sizes. A pointer, for example. A smart one preferably.

The difference between Java and C++ here is that Java automatically employs indirection for you, while C++ wants you to do this yourself. And as long as you use smart pointers you don't violate any of "best practices involving automatic memory allocation".

TL;DR The best practice in your case is to use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<General>>`.

Answer (score 1):

> Large structs (such as classes) should be passed by reference rather
>   than copied around and returned from functions

That's bullshit. On the contrary, you should *always* take *and* return by value unless there's a good reason not to. For the record, this applies to string too - I know you said you used `char*` for convenience *of writing this question*, but for future readers of this question, don't do that in your actual code. Use `std::string`, always.

A simple smart pointer (as in Ilya Kobelevskiy's answer) is more than sufficient to solve this problem.

There are other solutions too. For example, you could instead take a function and iterate over the objects, which doesn't require this.

```
template<typename T> void build(std::vector<std::string> things, T func) {
    for(auto str : things) {
        if(str == "A") {
            func(SpecificA());
        } else if(str == "B")) {
            func(SpecificB());
        }
    }
}
```

Now you may use it as a lambda.

```
int main() {
    auto things = /* insert things here */;
    build(things, [](const General& g) {
        // Don't miss the const, it's kinda important.
        g.f();
    });
}
```

Now you don't even have the problem of how to allocate the things, as they are just values. This is obviously not fully equivalent to what you had before but may be close enough, depending on what your actual use case is.

C++ is really not much like C or Java, and if you try to imagine that it is, you're just going to headdesk until you stop.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning the return value optimization here as a reason for returning the value.

Comment: "always take by value" is not a good advice. Copy elision is not neccessarily happening when passing arguments.

Comment: This isn't a micro optimization but being aware of what the language means + common sense...

Comment: Until the profiler told you to put it in, it's a micro-optimization.

Comment: Yes of course, rewriting your shared libraries api is just a good afterthought.

Comment: I am surprised to hear that from someone with 100K reputation. Which is a good thing, actually, since it means it worth nothing here and I should not crave one.

Comment: @Guest86: Oh noes, you might have to change your API for new requirements? Who'da thunk it? Of course, if you have a requirement for a particular speed beforehand, then you should have profiled beforehand and made the change beforehand, and then you're not changing anything.

Comment: Terrible, terrible ideas are spread here. Demanding that everything has a copy constructor (so that precious function can accept it by value) is one of those. I think, I better run from here.

Comment: Move constructors don't exist, amirite? And also being non-movable doesn't qualify as a good reason?

Comment: @Guest86, I think, Puppy is either trolling or confused. While there are solid reasons to return by value, there are none to prefer accepting by value to accepting by const reference - provided your argument does not change, as it should not.

Comment: No, but it's more than close enough to everything for the general case. If you ever try to accept a mutex by value in your function, you've probably got bigger problems than non-movability anyway.

Comment: Forget mutexes - though I see no issue in a function like 'try_locking_mutex_5_times_logging_every_attempt_with_stronger_term(). How about accepting streams by value? Say, ostream where your ostream& is cout?

Comment: There's not really much you can do about stuff like streams. They're defective in so many ways, playing poorly with the value ecosystem is just one of them. Besides, you seem to continually assume that every exception you can think of is not covered under "good reason".

Comment: yeah, just sprinkle your defective answer with 'good reasons', 'normal conditions', 'generally'  -and than whenever someone points to the defect in it, you can always claim this is not generic, good or normal. Way to go.

Comment: It's all of those things. That doesn't make it perfect. It's always down to the human programmer to exercise judgement from time to time. This is simply about making it so that you have to exercise judgement as little as possible.

Comment: @SergeyA - Puppy basically advised OP (who is, by his own words, novice to C++) to prefer std::string (over char*), to use std::unique_ptr (instead of raw), apply lambda (if possible) and don't care much for the time being about return by value (which is the job of compiler). All is true in this very case and generally nowadays. As a bonus, he corrected the code in the other answer to compile.  Just, kind of usual stuff for "someone with 100K reputation" on SO.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to create your objects on a heap and store the pointers in your collection. Like that:

```
std::vector<General*> build(char** things, int number) {
    std::vector<General*> result;
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++) {
        General* newObj = nullptr;
        if(strcmp(things[i],"A")) {
            newObj = new SpecificA();
        } else if(strcmp(things[i],"B")) {
            newObj = new SpecificB();
        }
        if(newObj != nullptr){
            result.push_back(newObj);  // you can do the "push" in one place
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or, to use the `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::vector< std::unique_ptr<General> > build(char** things, int number) {
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<General> > result;
    for(int i=0;i<number;i++) {
        std::unique_ptr<General> newObj;
        if(strcmp(things[i],"A")) {
            newObj = std::unique_ptr<General>(new SpecificA());
        } else if(strcmp(things[i],"B")) {
            newObj = std::unique_ptr<General>(new SpecificB());
        }
        if(newObj.get() != nullptr){
            result.push_back(newObj);  // you can do the "push" in one place
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Raw `new` is the bad. You should feel bad. Don't make bad answers please.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the "bad"?

Comment: The memory leaks? The exception unsafety? The double deletes? The buffer overflows?

Comment: Memory leaks are not automatically avoided by the use of garbage collectors, exception safety has nothing to do with the use of `new` versus managed pointers, double deletes are not avoided by the use of managed pointers, and buffer overflows have absolutely nothing to do with the use of managed pointers. However for completeness I have updated the answer to include the more extended version with the use of managed memory.

Comment: What on earth are you smoking? Memory leaks are automatically avoided by smart pointers, unless you do some weird and bad overuse of shared pointers leading to reference cycles. The same completely applies for exception safety (insofar as cleaning up the resources is concerned anyway) as they always clean up in the case of exception, and you can't randomly try to index into a shared_ptr so it's tough to accidentally overflow a bad index into it.